# complex sql query for finding the average working time of a person in office

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I need to retrieve using an oracle based query the working time of an employee which is the time coming in and time going out for an employee based on his transactions in the transaction table.

The transaction table has a date-time field which can be used for this purpose.

The steps involved would be as follows:
1) find the first transaction on a date and the last transaction on the same date - that would be his time in and timeout for that date
2) calculate the overall time-in as the avg of all time-ins on each date, similarly do for time-out

Transaction table is as follows: `transctn(transid, resourceid, event, currentdate)`

The second requirement is to find the average transactions performed each day, which is basically find the count of transids for each day and then average of that.

The final answer should be, when a userid is provided the query the return result is:

```
frequent working time(based on average): 9:43 am - 6:45 pm
average transactions performed/day = 43
```

How do I write the above requirement in oracle SQL or more smartly using Hibernate if Transctn is my Domain class

I have something like this:

```
select 'frequent working time: '
    ||(select rtrim(to_char(min(currentdate),'hh:mi pm')) from transctn)
    ||' - '||(select rtrim(to_char(max(currentdate),'hh:mi pm')) from transctn)
    ||', average transactions performed/day = '
    ||(select rtrim(to_char(count(distinct transid)/
        count(distinct(to_char(currentdate,'rrmmdd')))) from transctn)
from dual
```

Comment: I have something like this SELect 'frequent working time: '||(select rtrim(to_char(min(currentdate),'hh:mi pm')) from transctn)
||' - '||(select rtrim(to_char(max(currentdate),'hh:mi pm')) from transctn)
||', average transactions performed/day = '
||(select rtrim(to_char(count(distinct transid)/count(distinct (to_char(currentdate,'rrmmdd')))) from transctn) from dual

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your query has lots of selects from the same table stuck together, which isn't efficient, and makes it harder to read than necessary. And the `rtrim` isn't doing anything as you've already dictated the format. What you have can be rewritten as:

```
select 'frequent working time: '|| to_char(min(currentdate),'hh:mi pm')
        ||' - '|| to_char(max(currentdate),'hh:mi pm'),
    'average transactions performed/day = '
        || to_char(count(distinct transid)
            /count(distinct to_char(currentdate,'rrmmdd')))
from transctn;
```

But this isn't averaging properly, and isn't for a specific user. I'm join to assume this is homework and in the usual spirit of the site, try to give you pointers rather than the complete answer...

> 1) find the first transaction on a date and the last transaction on
>   the same date - that would be his time in and timeout for that date

You're not far off here, but you're breaking down by date. To get the time-in and time-out for every user, for each day, you could use:

```
select resourceid, trunc(currentdate), min(currentdate), max(currentdate)
from transctn
group by resourceid, trunc(currentdate)
order by resourceid, trunc(currentdate);
```

> 2) calculate the overall time-in as the avg of all time-ins on each
>   date, similarly do for time-out

You can't average dates directly in Oracle; you'd get `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE`. There are various ways to achieve the effect, you just need to figure out a safe way to treat the date - or more specifically here the time part - as a number. For example, you could treat the time portion as the difference between the actual time and the start of the day, which Oracle returns as a number:

```
select avg(min(currentdate) - trunc(currentdate)),
    avg(max(currentdate) - trunc(currentdate))
from transctn
group by trunc(currentdate);
```

But you than have to translate that fractional number back into something recognisable. One way of doing that is to add the number to an arbitrary fixed date, and then just extract the time part as a string as you were already doing:

```
select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + avg(min(currentdate) - trunc(currentdate)),
        'HH:MI pm') as avg_time_in,
    to_char(date '2000-01-01' + avg(max(currentdate) - trunc(currentdate)),
        'HH:MI pm') as avg_time_out
from transctn
group by trunc(currentdate);
```

This look messy and you might find a better way to do it. If it is homework then I would assume you've been taught methods for doing this sort of thing, or something that can be adapted to be applicable.

This is still for all resources, so you'll need to add a filter to restrict to one user ID. Hopefully this gives you some ideas for tackling the second requirement as well.